# Possible bug in Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, interface-builder

I've a window with a horizontal split view. On the bottom pane of the split view, I have a nssegmentedcontrol, aligned to the center. On the bottom of the nssegmentedcontrol I have 5 tabs that are controlled by the segmented control - click in one of the cells and the corresponding tab opens.

My problem is, if I completely minimize the bottom pane, to the point where the dividing line touches the bottom of the window, the segmented control gets pushed on top of the table header and never goes back to its original place.

I've tried fiddling with IB to get this to work, but no luck. Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Take a look at this StackOveflow Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248809/how-do-i-fix-the-height-of-my-view-after-collapsing-nssplitview 
It sounds similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following what's on the comments, I replaced the default split view with the one found in [BWToolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/) that allows for the definition of minimum and maximum height of each view.

Answer (score 0):

BWTookit is a no go, the framework leakes a lot.

You should use RBSplitView (google it), it also gives you option for min and max height
and I started using it because of a bug in the split view as well, I used it for a chat window
but the split view didn't autosave as it should, every time it got like 2px smaller,
RBSplitView is great, and doesn't leak.

Comment: If you've found leaks in BWToolkit, you should file bug reports with its author. I doubt he wants to publish a leaky framework any more than you want to use one.

Comment: I'd like to add that the author of BWToolkit is a nice guy willing to incorporate suggestions/bug fixes. I did that a few times in fact.

Comment: Yeah its a nice framework, but I just do not like leaks that's all :P
I love the bottom bar it can give to your windows..

Comment: How can I test for leaks in BWToolkit?

Comment: The comments here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248809/how-do-i-fix-the-height-of-my-view-after-collapsing-nssplitview/2157103#2157103) suggest the bugs in BWToolkit have been fixed.